# Does the Flex SOAP WebService dispatch ProgressEvents?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, soap

I'm currently building an application that will use a few SOAP web services. I've gotten them all to work just fine using the `mx.rpc.soap.WebService` class, but now I am seeing designs for the first time and they require a progress bar. Looking through the [mx.rpc live docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/package-detail.html), I have not found anything that resembles a `ProgressEvent` for this package. Is a `ProgressEvent` (or something similar) dispatched by these classes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer here is no, I've never seen any sort of progress related information on the web service classes (only implementations of IResponder getting fault or result).  For data that is being loaded using a Loader of some sort progress can be fetched, really this makes sense since large payloads you can measure how much has been sent.  With a request that does a lot of server side processing but doesn't produce a large payload this wouldn't be very useful.  Consider 2 options, use a timer to get faux progress, or use indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: @shaunhusain Well, one of the services has the potential of returning a 1-2MB file and our target audience could potentially be using dial-up range speeds. Progress bar is needed for that download, if it's possible. If not, we'll have to find a workaround obviously. Thanks for the response though

Comment: Depending on how much control you have on the service side you might be able to make use of this on the AS3 side to load the data with progress events http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html The issues I could see with this is possible issues with persisting a session or other data.  Also see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data